# basic text search in rails 3 and mongo db (mongoid)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I have some nifty javascript that serializes search input.

the controller has this:

```
@recipes = Recipe.where(name: params[:q])
```

right now it only returns results when theres an exact full word match - does anyone know of a way to make it return results which might contain the params[:q] even if its not an exact full match?

i.e. chicken should return chicken stew, chicken pot pie, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
@recipes = Recipe.where(name: /#{params[:q]}/i)
```

Comment: any idea how to make it case insensitive?